# Authenticating Curl HTTP Post

Tags: php, .net, curl, libcurl, soap-client

Hi I am trying to send POST request  through CURL but its throwing an error which says
"Failed connect to qaservices.carrental.com:443; No error".

The username and password is already included in the soap header in an xml file

```
<?php
$filename = 'c:/v.xml';
$data =  file_get_contents($filename);
$url = 'https://qaservices.carrental.com/wsbang/HTTPSOAPRouter/ws9071';
$soap_do = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );   
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true ); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HEADER,           0 ); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $data); 

$result = curl_exec($soap_do);
$err = curl_error($soap_do);  

if ( curl_errno($soap_do) )
{   
    $result = 'ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($soap_do) . ': ' . curl_error($soap_do);
}
else 
{   
    $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($soap_do, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   
    switch($returnCode)
    {      
        case 200:      
            break;    
        default:     
            $result = 'HTTP ERROR -> ' . $returnCode;        
            break; 
    }
}  
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

When i try to send HttpWebRequest in vb.net this works. the copy of code in vb.net is

```
       doc.Load("c:/v.xml")
        Dim content As String = doc.InnerXml
        Dim urlEncoded As String = content
        Dim encodedRequest As Byte() = New ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(urlEncoded)
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://qaservices.carrental.com/wsbang/HTTPSOAPRouter/ws9071"), HttpWebRequest)
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.Accept = "*/*"
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        '  request.UserAgent = "Custom REST client v1.0"
        request.ContentLength = encodedRequest.Length
                request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        Dim reqStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        reqStream.Write(encodedRequest, 0, encodedRequest.Length)
        reqStream.Flush()
        reqStream.Close()

        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = (request.GetResponse())

        Dim responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim streamReader As New StreamReader(responseStream)


        Dim responseContent As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd
```

I think it has to do something in setting up proxy credential Can anyone please guide me in correct path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A request for internet connection from curl/php was  refused the windows server. Some non microsoft application like fiddler, esclipse , maven will not connect to internet if your pc is connected to windows network. You need to install cntlm proxy which will add a header to you request so it can connect to internet.
I have configured cntlm to look on port 3127

In above code I added 
$proxy = '127.0.0.1:3127';
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);

Hope this help if someone is having a problem to connect to web using visual php on windows network

Answer (score 0):

Are both the SSL certificates valid on both host and your node? If not, then add the following options. This will bypass SSL verification and let you connect

```
curl_setopt ($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: Paste the output of `print_r(curl_getinfo($soap_do));`

Comment: Array ( [url] => https://qaservices.carrental.com/wsbang/HTTPSOAPRouter/ws9071 [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 1.498 [namelookup_time] => 0.499 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => 170.225.0.83 [primary_port] => 443

Comment: [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0 [redirect_url]